# erro na replicação

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando utilizar um comando no *shell* no PostgreSQL(Windows) com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
select pg_start_backup('nome do meu banco de dados', true);
```

Ele responde um registro. Agora, quando digito o comando a seguir não acontece nada:

```
pg_basebackup -U postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/db/secundario -P -h Ip do Slave -Ft
```

Quando dou esse comando:

```
pg_stop_backup();
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ph_basebackup"
>   LINHA 1: pg_basebackup -U postgres -D /var/li/psql/9.4/data/db/secu...

Alguém sabe o que esta acontecendo?

Desde já agradeço, obrigado!

Comment: Se possível, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/53324/edit) sua pergunta explicando o que está tentando fazer, o que tentou. Um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) também pode ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que dá para ver pela sua pergunta, você está tentando criar um servidor SLAVE a partir do seu master.

1 - Instale o RSYNC no seu master e no seu servidor slave. 
Se for CentOS/Fedora/Red hat:

```
yum install -y rsync
```

2 - Crie um usuário `REPLICATOR` no seu servidor Master (se ainda não fez):

```
psql -c "CREATE USER replicator REPLICATION LOGIN CONNECTION LIMIT 5 ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'suasenhaaqui';"
```

3 - No seu servidor master, mude os seguintes parâmetros no postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = ‘*’
wal_level = 'hot_standby'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
max_wal_senders = 1
hot_standby = on
```

4 - No arquivo `pg_hba.conf`, altere o seguinte:

```
host    replication     replicator     endereco_ip_do_slave/32   md5
```

5 - Reinicie o seu servidor Postgres master:

```
service postgresql-9.6 restart
```

6 - Para iniciar o `RSYNC`, para que tenhamos uma cópia do seu banco no servidor slave, execute os passos à seguir no seu servidor master: (**Não esqueça que você precisa do *PASSO NÚMERO 3* aqui**)

```
psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"
rsync -cva --inplace /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/ ip_servidor_slave:/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/
psql -c "select pg_stop_backup();"
```

Após o passo à cima, lembre de ter o recovery.conf [1] no seu slave antes de iniciar o Postgres.

Você também irá precisar alterar o `pg_hba.conf` no seu slave para:

```
host    replication     replicator     endereco_ip_do_master/32   md5
```